# Jboss.as mbean missing after enable jmx remote wildfly 9.0.2 Final

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jmx, mbeans, wildfly-9

I am having to extract information from the datasource and other JMX information in wildfly 9.0.2.Final. When I enable JMX in wildfly the Jboss.as mbean simply disappears and I do not know what to do.

Below is the image of the mbean map extracted from JCONSOLE, without activating JMX:

[Image_Mbean_jconsole_without_JMX_enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtHk4.png)

Below is the image of the mbean map extracted from JCONSOLE, activating JMX REMOTE:

[Image_Mbean_jconsole_with_JMX_enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFYuA.png)

Below is JAVA_OPTS that I am adding to activate JMX REMOTE:

```
JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.0.Final.jar -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

All the commands added start Wildfly without any problems. The tests carried out, are of the official Wildfly image without any configuration outside this posted here.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this. How is JMX disabled in the first screen shot?

Comment: In first screen shot i did not configure JMX and jboss.as mbean  it is acessible. That is, it is wildfly with default configuration.

But when configuring JMX the jboss.as mbean inacessible. (second screen)

Comment: JMX is already there and started by default on WildFly. This is what I don't understand. There's nothing to enable.

Comment: I need to access JMX from a remote computer through a communication port.

Maybe I'm wrong, but I do not need to add the "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote" option on wildfly?

Below is a link of what I'm trying to do:
Https://gist.github.com/rponte/1173847

Comment: You don't need those system properties. All you need to do is allow WildFly's management interface to listen on a public IP. So something like `.$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -bmanagement 0.0.0.0`. Just leave all the `com.sun.management` system properties out of the JAVA_OPTS.